# mongoose Mongodb schema (nodejs) One to many Mapping

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-schema, bson, mongoose-schema

Hi i am new to mongodb

I have the following requirement for a music library application

[image: RDBMS Schema]

I need to design this tabular data into mongoose schema

I need to query comments based on album,user

Somebody help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume it's difficult to change the way we create tables into the way we create collections. I will give you one advice : what is your critical app data ? I think there is two collections (User and Album) and then you can add an array of comments inside the album document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the detailed description for beginners on how to design mongo schemas

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1